# What is the difference between 生成{せいせい} and 作成{さくせい}?

Tags: meaning, dictionary

What is the difference between 生成{せいせい} and 作成{さくせい}?

> 例:ソースファイル生成

As per my point of view 生成 and 作成 gives same meaning. Please explain clearly with example where should we use 生成 and where should we use 作成.

**Dictionary**

> 生成 - creation; generation 
>   作成 - making; producing; creating; creation

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

作成 means you directly create something with your effort, creative sense, etc. When you write source code by hand, that's 作成, not 生成.

生成 sounds like a machine generates something — a compiler generating executable files, a voice synthesizer, a logger generating log files, and so on. ソースファイルの生成 sounds like you are using some source code generator.

Sometimes 作成 and 生成 can be used almost interchangeably. `Stirng s = new String('foo')` can be described as both オブジェクトの作成 and オブジェクトの生成. Still, the former sounds like *you* created it, and the latter sounds like *the machine* created it.

Comment: After reading you answer, I compared with some technical document and looks perfect answer. Thank you very much.